# Why do I need to use double asterisk? **

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

C++
In theory, if I have a class made, called `Box`. And I have all the variables and services done etc. If I'm asked to create a program in which I need to create a pointer class variable that is a dynamic array.

Why do I need to use ex: `Box **boxes= nullptr;` ?

Also, if I'm asked that in addition to declaring that Box name boxes I need to declare an integer variable size equal to 0:

```
int size = 0;
```

How would a function called `void addBox(Box** box, int &size)` be done so that every time I call it I add the parameters for box and another box is added to the dynamic array?

FYI, I'm new to coding and I need to apply this concept to a project from class.

Comment: `Why do I need to use ex: Box **boxes= nullptr;` You don't.

Comment: `type**` is a single pointer to another pointer of type `type`. (say `Box **boxes;`) If you allocate storage for multiple pointers and assign the beginning address to your pointer, you can index each pointer in the allocated block as `boxes[0], boxes[1], ...`. If you then assign the address to an instance of `class Box` to each of the pointers in turn, you can use each of the instances as `boxes[i]->member`, etc.

Comment: Additionally, `void addBox(Box** box, int &size)` looks like a function to add an instance of type `Box` to a linked-list (or stack, or queue...). In that case, you may be passing the *address_of* a single instance of class `Box` (generally the `head` node in a list or top of a stack with linked nodes). You are passing the address of the pointer so you can update the address of the original pointer in the function so the change will survive return (in C++ you can also pass a reference to the pointer). If you simply pass a pointer, the function receives a "copy" and changes are lost on return..

Comment: It sounds like your instructor doesn't know how to teach C++. It really should be `void addBox(std::vector<Box> & boxes)`, or a member function of `namespace learning { class box_vector {  ... } }`

Answer (score 6):

Let me answer why ** is needed instead of *
Counter-intuitively, if we use * and code, here's what a sample looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box { //Some Example class
public:
  int val{10};
};


void addBox(Box* box, int &size) { //Implementation using *
  box = new Box;
  size++;
  return;
}

int main() {
  Box *bptr{nullptr};
  int size{0};
  addBox(bptr, size);
  cout << bptr->val << endl;
}
```

Just after addBox is called, before execution, the memory would look like this:
[image]

When addBox calls `new` and allocates a new Box object on the heap, memory would look like:
[image]

But, when scope of `addBox()` completes and control goes back to main, the heap memory location is no longer adddressable, `bptr` still has `nullptr`
[image]

So, `bptr->val` would throw segmentation fault.

---

But on the other hand, if we use a double pointer(**), this would be the code─

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box { //Some Example class
public:
  int val{10};
};

void addBox(Box** box, int &size) {
  *box = new Box;
  size++;
  return;
}

int main() {
  Box *bptr{nullptr};
  int size{0};
  addBox(&bptr, size);
  cout << bptr->val << endl;
}
```

Just after `addBox()` is called:

[image]

`new` allocation:

[image]

Finally, when we return to `main`, the heap allocation information is intact.
[image]

And call `bptr->val` will print value correctly as 10.
For your assignment, you need to keep track of each call to `addBox`, it comes under the concept of a linked-list.